# What makes Crystal ignore record selection formula?

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

Crystal 2008.  Have record selection formula ending with

```
and 
   (    ( "Zero"   in {?Credit_Debit} and {V_ARHB_BKT_AGING_DETAIL.AMOUNT} = 0)
     or ( "Credit" in {?Credit_Debit} and {V_ARHB_BKT_AGING_DETAIL.AMOUNT} < 0)
     or ( "Debit"  in {?Credit_Debit} and {V_ARHB_BKT_AGING_DETAIL.AMOUNT} > 0) )
```

but no matter what combination of values is selected for Credit_Debit the result set is the same.

Also without success, I tried joining the parameter array into a single string and using lines like

```
 or ( {@Cred_Deb_Choices} like "*Credit*" and {V_ARHB_BKT_AGING_DETAIL.AMOUNT} < 0)
```

Using the first method works in the same formula when the parameter values are integers, as:

```
and ({?Location ID} = 0 or {V_ARHB_BKT_AGING_DETAIL.LOC_ID} in {?Location ID})
```

I examined the generated SQL, and saw that the part at the beginning that had no effect was not shown.

I changed a part that tested for a hard-coded value to instead test for a parameter value, and looked at the SQL again.  No change.

Comment: I haven't used CR in a while and I don't have access to a copy, but I recall having this problem and solving it.  Is there a menu setting/option you have to turn on?

Comment: I haven't found one, but it's worth looking--even though "silently ignore edits" would be a rather stupid thing to put on a menu.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you try to create a filter that doesn't fit with the datatype of the field then that doesn't get reflected in record selection formula.

For Integer field give integers in record selection for text give text.

```
E.g:
ID=0 and Name='XXX' works
ID='Zero' and Name='XXX' doesn't
```

This should solve your issue

Comment: I don't think that's it, but it's worth remembering.  I would consider that a serious bug, to respond to a programmer's error by pretending he hadn't typed anything.

Comment: In fact that isn’t it.  The string parameter is being compared to the string literal in the formula, not to a field from the database.